# Regex that replaces characters that break strings

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, I'm hoping one can do this with preg_replace and a regex replace all `'` with `\'` and all `"` with `\"` and all `/` with `\/`.

So replace all characters that can break a string with their escape character counterparts.

Comment: `/` don't break string

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: `addslashes`?  But why do you want to do it?  It's probably for the wrong reason.

Comment: @m.buettne: unless he is creating an expression for another engine (like sql query)

Comment: @zerkms forget what I said, it's getting late.

Comment: PS: I'll just leave it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2):

This

```
$string = str_replace(Array('"', "'"), Array('\"', "\'"), $string);
```

or this

```
$string = addslashes($string);
```

should do he trick.

I recommend the second. The first should work well to.

`preg_replace` might cause the code to run a lot slower then the other options.

Answer (score 1):

*str_replace* and *addslashes* are good ways to do that. With a *preg_replace*, don't forget the triple backslash:

```
$string = <<<'LOD'
I 'love' "marmots" \
LOD;

echo $string.'<br>'.preg_replace('~["\'\\\]~', '\\\$0', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that with preg_replace, but in your case I might suggest simply using `str_replace()` or `addslashes()`.